# Error when trying to connect to Jacorb naming service

Tags: java, corba

I'm hoping to get some help with this weird problem. We're running the Jacorb name server and I have a simple client that I'm using to try to connect and do awesome CORBA voodoo. The name server is running, but when I try to start my java app, I get a `"Connection failure" error (org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE, minor code 201, "caused by java.net.ConnectionException: Connection refused: connect")`.

Here's the weird part. The error reports that it's trying to connect using the default port 900, but I'm passing in an argument to try to override the port number of the name service to match the one being used by the name server. My java command is like this:

```
java -classpath . HelloClient -Djava.endorsed.dirs="bla bla bla" <br>
-Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBClass=org.jacorb.orb.ORB 
-Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBSingletonClass=org.jacorb.orb.ORBSingleton
-DORBInitRef.NameService=corbaloc::localhost:2809/StandardNS/NameServer-POA/_root
```

I also tried the parameters without the first capital D (I've seen it both ways and I don't know the difference).

Now, if I put in `-ORBInitialPort 2809`, then the client does appear to try to connect, but then I get a `corba.OBJECT_NOT_EXIST` error.

I could use any help or advice anyone has.

Comment: Wow, no one even venturing a guess? I feel disappointed :\

Comment: Could you post your Java code where you are trying to establish a connection to the name server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connection Refused.  This sounds like a firewall/program not running issue.
try a `telnet <machine> 2809`.  You should get a "Connected to " 
and not a refusal, if everything is running/enabled correctly.

I'm running on a UNIX client so the paths use UNIX style.

1. jacORB installed properly ? e.g. get the nameservice entry from the
   orb.properties file (in ${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/
   I use "`ORBInitRef.NameService=corbaloc::localhost:2809/NameServer`" 
   as "NameServer" is used on the production name server and not the other 
   string of "Standard...."

   The other changes in the properties files are setting the paths to UNIX
   style (i.e. e:\NS_Ref -> /tmp/NS_Ref)
   `jacorb.naming.ior_filename=/tmp/NS_Ref`

1a. Setting the http:// in the properties file didn't seem to do anything
    in regards to resolving on the client side.

1b. NOTE: start ns with:
    `ns -DOAPort=2809`

Log will show:
`2010-05-27 10:00:47.777 FINE Created socket listener on 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2809`
`2010-05-27 10:00:47.777 FINE Using port 2809`
Running:
`$ lsof | grep 2809
java      27529   jbsymolo   15u     IPv6     693300 TCP *:2809 (LISTEN)
$ lsof -Pnl +M -i6
COMMAND     PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE NODE NAME
Naming_Se  9678     1000    7u  IPv6  45779       TCP *:51148 (LISTEN)
java      27959     1000   15u  IPv6 696092       TCP *:2809 (LISTEN)`

Not Running: (shows nothing)

2. ns when started will log where it reads the properties from and it shouldn't
   throw any errors.  If it does your properties files have issues.
3. VM arguments. The -D is used to set system properties. Any Java code can 
   then access any property so defined via System.getProperty(). Even though 
   I've also seen the "non-D" used, I've been using the D.

   > -DORBInitRef.NameService=corbaloc::localhost:2809/NameService
   >   -Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBClass=org.jacorb.orb.ORB
   >   -Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBSingletonClass=org.jacorb.orb.ORBSingleton

When running the client in Eclipse, I see the following in the Console:

```
May 27, 2010 10:01:06 AM org.jacorb.config.JacORBConfiguration init
INFO: base configuration loaded from file /usr/lib/java/jdk1.6.0_18/jre/lib/orb.properties
...
2010-05-27 10:01:09.836 FINE Trying to connect to 127.0.0.1:2809 with timeout=90000.
2010-05-27 10:01:09.844 INFO Connected to 127.0.0.1:2809 from local port 45745
2010-05-27 10:01:09.846 FINE wrote 12 bytes to 127.0.0.1:2809
...
```

Skipping lots of other read/write traffic

Comment: Hi Jim, Can you please tell me how are you able to configure timeout to 90000 ms

Comment: # Wait the specified number of msecs for a reply to a request. If
# exceeded, a org.omg.CORBA.IMP_LIMIT exception will be thrown
#jacorb.client.pending_reply_timeout=0

Comment: # client-side connection idle timeout, set no non-zero to stop
# blocking after so many msecs.
#
# WARNING: This is independent of pending replies, i.e. the connection
# can also close, if the timeout is exceeded, but there are unanswered
# requests.
#jacorb.connection.client_idle_timeout=0

Comment: # max time a server keeps a connection open if nothing happens
#
# WARNING: This is independent of the requests currently being
# processed, i.e. the connection can also close, if the timeout is
# exceeded, but there are unanswered requests.
#
#jacorb.connection.server_timeout=10000

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure without seeing the rest of the code, but I'm pretty sure you need to change the InitRef string to be:

```
-DORBInitRef.NameService=corbaloc::localhost:2809
```

When your client connects, this should give you the root naming context for the naming service and then you can traverse the NameContext tree to get to your desired server object.